# Mirror Vertex Group in Weight Paint no working (Blender 3.0)

Tags: weight-painting, mirror, vertex-groups

In Blender3.0, I create the left side of bones, In pose mode, auto name left-right, then symmetry. Then set parent to mesh as empty weight.

But as you can see in the image, when I paint the left side (fr.eyebrow.000.L) while opening the Mirror Vertex group, the right side(fr.eyebrow.000.R) is not painted.

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

These two switchers should be enabled:

**Mirror vertex groups** an "**X**"

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering, but seems like it doesn't work for me. If I open both "Mirror vertex groups" and "X", my paint still has no symmetry. If I only open "X", my paint only have symmetry on the same vertex group.

Comment: I see the similar Blender bug, enabling Mirror Vertex Group checkbox and paint on Right bone and all mirroring happens still on right side, I click on Left bone and see all painting on Right side, I have _Left and _Right vertex groups. Blender is doing something completely unexpected. I can no longer use Symmetry paint in Blender 3.3